# Is it possible to return string values from a query when using Entity-Framework?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework

So far I know two ways to query the database. One of it is by using MySQL's Libraries; By declaring "MySqlCommand", "MySqlDataReader", "MySqlConnection" and utilizing the inbuilt methods.

And another is through using the Entity Framework (Which is my preferred option).

I've however run into a bit of a problem with this later method. I personally blame my lack of knowledge. It would seem that when conveying data to the end user, Entity-Framework favours the ObservableCollection<> or List<>.

For me, this means that in the View, I'd be using a Datagrid or List control. Normally this would be fine.

But then, what happens if I don't want a datagrid control in the mix? What if I want the query's result conveyed in a textboxes? How can I do the below without sacrificing the usage of the entity framework? Is it even possible?

```
        string config = "server=localhost; userid = root; database = databaseName";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(config);

        MySqlDataReader reader = null;

        // Run the select query
        string query = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = " +id;

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Put the results in the appropriate strings so I can databind them
            string studentName = (string)reader["studentName"];

            string studentNum = (string)reader["studentNum"];

            .....
        }
        con.Close();
```

How could I do this utilising the entity framework?

Comment: you can use SingleOrDefault() instead of ToList() or simple iterate through your List result and add the values to associated textboxes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EF equivalents for this SQL query:

```
// note, that this leads to SQL injections,
// use parametrized queries instead!
"SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = " +id
```

will be:

```
var student = context.Students.Find(id) // this will lookup local data as well
```

or:

```
var student = context.Students.Single(_ => _.Id == id)
```

Both will return single `Student` instance, not a sequence/collection, and you can bind your UI to its properties or access them as usual:

```
student.StudentName
```

Comment: Alright. That makes sense. Just one tiny detail. How I access these properties which I need to bind to? I get how the query is done, I see `context.Students` but how would I find (for example) the `StudentName` field inside `context.students`? 
I mean at the end of it all, I still need to put the value inside a string or int right?

Comment: @Offer: I've updated answer. Just call properties as usual.

Comment: And that did it. Much gratitude.

Answer (score 3):

Try to something like that:

```
public static Studens GetStudent(int id)
{    
    return context.Studens.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id == id);
}
```

Comment: don't do `.Any` then `.First` - just do `.SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: why dont `return context.Studens.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id == id);`

Comment: @MantasČekanauskas Thank you. I've modified the answer according to your advice.